# Android - AutoCompleteTextView onClickListener works after second click

Tags: android

I have four `AutoCompleteTextView`s (ACTV) and they're working just fine. I created an `onClickListener()` for them to know when a user selects/presses any of the four at any point in time. However, upon close inspection, I noticed that I had to click an ACTV twice before it was triggered.

Here is my code:

In my `onCreate()`, I initialize the actv and set the `onClickListener()`:

```
brandACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvBrand);
itemACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvItemName);
partACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvPart);
barcodeACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvBarcode);
    
brandACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
itemACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
partACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
barcodeACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
```

and the `onClickListener()` is defined like so:

```
OnClickListener actvClicked = new OnClickListener(){
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        
        Log.d("Hi", "onClickActivated");

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.actvBrand:
                Log.d("Hi", "Brand pressed");
                break;
            
            case R.id.actvItemName:
                Log.d("Hi", "Item name pressed");
                break;
            
            case R.id.actvPart:
                Log.d("Hi", "Part pressed");
                break;
                
            case R.id.actvBarcode:
                Log.d("Hi", "Barcode pressed");
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

However, only the initial click is detected properly. All subsequent clicks only register once the user clicks the same actv twice.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used onFocusChangedListener instead. Like so:

```
    brandACTV.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChanged);
    itemACTV.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChanged);
    partACTV.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChanged);
    barcodeACTV.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChanged);
```

and then the listener is defined as such:

```
OnFocusChangeListener focusChanged = new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        Log.d("Hi", "Id is " + v.getId() + ". Focus is " + hasFocus);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch( v.getId() ){
            case R.id.actvBrand:
                Log.d("Hi", "Brand focus is + " + hasFocus);
                break;

            case R.id.actvItemName:
                Log.d("Hi", "ItemName focus is + " + hasFocus);
                break;

            case R.id.actvPart:
                Log.d("Hi", "Part focus is + " + hasFocus);
                break;

            case R.id.actvBarcode:
                Log.d("Hi", "Barcode focus is + " + hasFocus);
                break;

        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brandACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvBrand);
itemACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvItemName);
partACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvPart);
barcodeACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvBarcode);

brandACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
itemACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
partACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
barcodeACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
```

and the `onClickListener` is defined like so:

```
OnClickListener actvClicked = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

        Log.d("Hi", "onClickActivated");

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.actvBrand:
            actvBrand.requestFocus();
                Log.d("Hi", "Brand pressed");
                break;

            case R.id.actvItemName:
             actvItemName.requestFocus();
                Log.d("Hi", "Item name pressed");
                break;

            case R.id.actvPart:
         actvPart.requestFocus();
                Log.d("Hi", "Part pressed");
                break;

            case R.id.actvBarcode:
                actvBarcode.requestFocus();
                Log.d("Hi", "Barcode pressed");
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: try this... this might help

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, what did you change in the first block of code? Also, did you mean `brandACTV.requestFocus();` instead of `actvBrand.requestFocus();`? How would `requestFocus()` help if I can't even get inside the `case` statement? This solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove focus from `AutoCompleteTextView`:
go to your XML and add this attributes `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: If I set focusable to false, how am I supposed to type into the AutoCompleteTextView?